# Angular animation does not work

Tags: css, angularjs

I'm trying to use show animation on a div,

```
<div class="animate-show title span3" ng-show="status.processing"  ng-bind="status.message" >

        </div>
```

and the css has

```
.animate-show.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active, .animate-show.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove- active {
-webkit-transition: 1s linear all;
-moz-transition: 1s linear all;
-ms-transition: 1s linear all;
-o-transition: 1s linear all;
transition: 1s linear all;
}

.animate-show.ng-hide {
line-height:0;
opacity:0;
padding:0 10px;
 }

.animate-show {
line-height:20px;
opacity:1;
padding:10px;
  }
```

Any suggestion why this won't work? I see my div show and hide but no animation running.

Comment: The transition has to be on the root element.

Comment: Why aren't  you using ngClass and then tying the animations to that class? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: I guess you can't animate `display` say `block` to `none` using a transition. Edit: oops, sorry, my bad, didn't notice the CSS

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add ng-enter / ng-leave classes in your CSS.
Also, define the transition state on animate-show before any animations occur, hence remove things like `ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active`

Try:

```
.animate-show{
    -webkit-transition: 1s linear all;
    -moz-transition: 1s linear all;
    -ms-transition: 1s linear all;
    -o-transition: 1s linear all;
    transition: 1s linear all;
}

.animate-show.ng-hide
.animate-show.ng-leave {
    line-height:0;
    opacity:0;
    padding:0 10px;
}

.animate-show,
.animage-show.ng-enter,
.animage-show.ng-move {
    line-height:20px;
    opacity:1;
    padding:10px;
}
```

If you don't want to use ng-show, here is an example which uses ng-class: http://plnkr.co/edit/FQDRUkSoellXEFMET33z?p=preview

Comment: Hi, I see that your example is working. but for some reason not works for me.

Comment: I see that for some reason if i use ng-hide instead of ng show i can see the div for a little more time, why is that?